# Meteor package still giving error even though the packages has not been added

Tags: meteor

I keep getting the error in console

```
W20150601-13:28:19.607(-4)? (STDERR) The spacjamio:chai package has been renamed to practicalmeteor:chai. Please use the new package name instead.
```

But the spacjamio:chai package has not been added to my project. Why do I keep getting this message?

When I search the hidden meteor build folder I do see a js file for the spacjamio:chai package. Do I just delete this?

Here is my package list

```
meteor-platform
accounts-password
stylus
mquandalle:jade
coffeescript
sacha:spin
natestrauser:font-awesome
multiply:iron-router-progress
iron:router
alanning:roles
twbs:bootstrap
msavin:mongol
msavin:jetsetter
random
cmather:handlebars-server
email
mrt:moment
themeteorchef:bert
cunneen:mailgun
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
aldeed:simple-schema
zimme:collection-timestampable
aldeed:collection2
mike:mocha
practicalmeteor:chai
```

UPDATE:

The error seems to stop when I remove the mike:mocha package. But mike:mocha package seems to require the newest name for chai package.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add it and don't need it, I'd just remove it with...

```
meteor remove practialmeteor:chai
```

in the console. Worth a shot at least, if it breaks stuff you can always add it back.

Comment: well the message was coming up before I added 'practialmeteor:chai' 'practialmeteor:chai' is the correct name. 'spacjamio:chai' is the incorrect name and I canot figure out how to get rid of it. I tried adding the right name package but still get the error.

Comment: Ah my bad, didn't realize you were keeping the correct one. Have you tried meteor remove \*old name* ?

Comment: yup tried that and it reports that the package is not added to the project

Comment: if you look at my package list, do you suspect any other package except mike:mocha using chai package?

Comment: @nearpoint coffeescript might have chai as a dependent, not sure about any others though.

Comment: i found out if I remove mike:mocha the error stops. It seems like it is an issue with mike:mocha package

Comment: @nearpoint Hm, checking mocha's [atmosphere.js page](https://atmospherejs.com/mike/mocha) it seems that it's dependent on the correct version of chai. Perhaps you don't have the most recent version?

Comment: I have the most recent version. I submitted a github issue. https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-mocha-web/issues/174#issuecomment-107691682